# Is there anyway I can make a template<typename T> accept multiple values?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I wrote this code, and it currently can accept one void callback and pass one value to it.  However, is there any way I can make the user able to set multiple args? Perhaps something like Callback Caller; instead of Callback without defining multiple typenames? Can I fit this all into one typename somehow?

For example, here is my class

```
template <typename T>
class Callback
{
private:
    std::vector<std::function <void (T)>> func;
public:
    virtual void operator += (std::function<void (T)> _func)
    {
        func.push_back(_func);
    }

};
```

I use it like this:

```
Callback<int> Test;
```

And it works just fine if I want to pass only one argument to my function.  However, is it possible to make the user able to define multiple values, without having more than one typename?

I.e.

```
Callback< <(int, int, int)> > Test;
```

Something similar to that?

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` in C++11 to construct it in place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++11, use variadic templates:

```
template <typename... Ts>
//                ^^^^^^ Parameter pack
class Callback
{
private:
    std::vector<std::function <void (Ts...)>> func;
//                                   ^^^^^
//                                   Parameter pack expansion
public:
    virtual void operator += (std::function<void (Ts...)> _func)
//                                                ^^^^^
//                             Parameter pack expansion             
    {
        func.push_back(_func);
    }
};
```

Now you can instantiate your class this way:

```
Callback<int, int, int>
Callback<double, std::string>
Callback<bool>
Callback<>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  I'm going to read about packing parameters to learn more.

Comment: @Jason: OK, glad I could help. If this answers your question, please consider marking the answer as accepted when the system will allow you :)

Answer (score 1):

without C++0x you can use `boost::mpl::set` to pass a set of types.
If you need the order of arguments, than use `boost::mpl::vector`.

See http://www.boost.org for more details.